# How to add "Freezer" control group to Fedora 36, and does it matter for virtualization if I don't?

Tags: fedora, virtual-machine, kvm, cgroups

I'm trying to (re)install KVM on my development system (which has been often-upgraded over the years since Fedora twenty-something, and on which kvm was installed many moons ago and then forgotten about, in case this is relevant)

After working out how to enable virtualization on my AMD Ryzen CPU (it was disabled in the BIOS), `# virt-host-validate` now `FAIL`s on `cgroup 'freezer' controller support`. Everything else is PASSing as expected.

On the other hand, I am able to create a Virtual Machine even with this FAIL state.

So, does anyody know how I can fix this, or what are the implications of it not being available?

I have tried re-installing the `virtualization` group packages, and I have tried booting with `cgroup_enable=freezer` added to the kernel command line. Neither changed anything.

I'm running Fedora 36 with kernel 6.0.16-200.fc36.x86_64

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the check is only relevant for LXC (a *container* framework that may managed via libvirt) and has nothing to do with virtual machines, KVM-based or otherwise.

Second, the check is a relic from cgroups v1, where each controller had to be separately mounted as a virtual filesystem tree (with no single place to put "misc" features except by making a controller for them).

The currently used "cgroups v2" interface has a unified tree for all controllers, so the ability to freeze processes of a cgroup is now just part of the baseline cgroup interface instead of being a separate controller.